# How can I input a logical proposition using a compact (implicit) notation?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I have:

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{n=1}^{9} \bigvee_{j=1}^{9}~p(i,j,n)$$

How can I write it in Wolfram Mathematica code?

I tried this way, but it does not work:

```
ToExpression["\\bigwedge_{i=1}^{9} \\bigwedge_{n=1}^{9} \\bigvee_{j=1}^{9}~p(i,j,n)",TeXForm]
```

> During evaluation of In[2]:= ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse \bigwedge_{i=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{n=1}^{9} \bigvee_{j=1}^{9}~p(i,j,n) as input.
>
> $Failed

What is the mistake in my above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Mathematica can only parse its own language, not $\LaTeX$. The Mathematica equivalent would be

```
P = Array[p, {9, 9, 9}];
Apply[And,
  Apply[And,
   Apply[Or,
    Transpose[P, {1, 3, 2}],
    {2}],
   {1}],
  {0}];
```

Comment: But what about this `ToExpression["input",TeXForm]`? From here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneratingAndImportingTeX.html `convert TeX input to the Wolfram Language`?

Comment: $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are interpreted quite differently among various mathematical  subdisciplines, so Mathematica cannot assign unique meanings to them. Best is not to rely on such a way to code. See, `ToExpression["\\sum_{i=1}^10 i", TeXForm]` results in `0`; complete nonsense.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial/book/etc where is explained notation that is used in proposition in my post? Currently reading discrete math book but there is no explanation of that notation. I even do not know what to search in google to find that information. I tryied to search "index notation", "array notation", "compact for of propositions" but without luck. Maybe you know?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean. In mathematical logic, $\wedge$ means "and" and $\vee$ stands for "or". The notations of the form $\bigvee_{i=1}^9$ and $\bigwedge_{i=1}^9$ are analogous to the sum notation $\sum_{i=1}^9$. The latter should be explained in the first chapters of any beginner's analysis textbook.

Comment: Only single character superscripts are supported by Mathematica's TeXForm parser. Using `ToExpression["\\sum_{i=1}^{10} i", TeXForm]` works.

Comment: @CarlWoll Oh my, you're so right. =/

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Maybe code should look like this `P = Array[p, {9, 9, 9}]; Apply[And, Apply[And, Apply[Or, P, {2}], {1}], {0}]` ?

Comment: Hm. Not sure. The last index appearing in $p$ in your expression is the $n$ which belongs to the $\bigwedge$, so I applied `And` to the the last slot of the array `P`.

Comment: Here is the calculation done by hand: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2893114/41724  I think *Array* should look like: `P = Array[p[#1, #3, #2] &, {9, 9, 9}]`  But there is a problem with correct *Apply* functions. I tried your example but it is incorrect. I tryied this  `Apply[And, Apply[And, Apply[Or, P, {2}], {1}], {0}]` but I think that the AND for `i=1` is not applied correctly. Can you please check what is the problem?

Comment: You're absolutely right: Of course `And` and `Or` do not commute, so we have to apply `Or` first along the `j`-indices. In `P = Array[p, {9, 9, 9}];`, this is level 1, so that we can either aplly `Or` to level 2 in `Transpose[P, {1, 3, 2}]` or redefine `P = Array[p[#1, #3, #2] &, {9, 9, 9}]`. Sorry that I confused you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to input your notation into Mathematica directly, you can define special [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression) rules:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{UnderoverscriptBox["\[Wedge]",u__],r_}],form_]:=Replace[
    MakeExpression[RowBox[{UnderoverscriptBox["\[Sum]",u],r}],form],
    HoldComplete[Sum[a__]]:>HoldComplete[NaryWedge[a]]
]
NaryWedge[e_, iter_] := With[{list = Table[e, iter]},
    And @@ list /; ListQ @ list
]

MakeExpression[RowBox[{UnderoverscriptBox["\[Vee]",u__],r_}],form_]:=Replace[
    MakeExpression[RowBox[{UnderoverscriptBox["\[Sum]",u],r}],form],
    HoldComplete[Sum[a__]]:>HoldComplete[NaryVee[a]]
]
NaryVee[e_, iter_] := With[{list = Table[e, iter]},
    Or @@ list /; ListQ @ list
]
```

For example:

[image]

> $p(7)\lor p(8)\lor p(9)$

Now, you might like to have the vee and wedge symbols slightly larger. To do this we can introduce input auto replacement rules:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{InputAutoReplacements,"vv"}] = StyleBox[
    "\[Vee]",
    FontWeight->Plain,
    FontFamily->"Impact"
];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{InputAutoReplacements,"ww"}] = StyleBox[
    "\[Wedge]",
    FontWeight->Plain,
    FontFamily->"Impact"
];
```

A short animation:

[image]

Comment: I pasted that code and executed. After I write `ww` and press `Space`. There appears $\bigwedge$ but the cursor is to the right side of $\bigwedge$. How can I input upper and lower part of that $\bigwedge$?

Comment: Use Ctrl-4 for underscript and Ctrl-5 to switch between under and overscript. See this [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTwoDimensionalInput) for more details.

Comment: Very good example. It works great! Thank you.