# Logical equivalence of logical propositions that are converted from compact (implicit) notation to Mathematica code

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

Here is logical formula:

$$\bigwedge_{i=1}^{9} \bigwedge_{n=1}^{9} \bigvee_{j=1}^{9}~p(i,j,n)$$

To use it in Mathematica I [use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180580/how-can-i-input-a-logical-proposition-using-a-compact-implicit-notation) that code:

```
X=Array[p[#1,#3,#2]&,{9,9,9}];a=Apply[And,Apply[And,Apply[Or,X,{2}],{1}],{0}];
Y=Array[p,{9,9,9}];b=Apply[And,Apply[And,Apply[Or,Transpose[Y,{1,3,2}],{2}],{1}],{0}];
c = 0
```

Two methods are used above. In the first one, I am putting the result in `a` variable and with the second method in `b` variable.

Now:

```
MatchQ[a,b]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[a,c]
```

> False

So, I conclude that the output of `a` and `b` are the same.

Now I want to check the *logical equivalence* of `a` and `b`.

I tried:

```
TrueQ[Equivalent[a, b]]
```

> True

```
TrueQ[Equivalent[a, c]]
```

> False

```
TrueQ[Equal[a,b]]
```

> True

```
TrueQ[Equal[a,c]]
```

> False

```
SameQ[a,b]
```

> True

```
SameQ[a,c]
```

> False

---

**Questions:**

1. What is called the content of `a` and  `b`? Logical formula? Function(s)? Normal expression? Object? Other?
2. Are the all ways of checking the *logical equivalence* of `a` and `b` that I have used above right?
3. Are there any other possible ways to check the *logical equivalence* of `a` and `b` that I have not used above?
4. Is there one best way to check the *logical equivalence* of `a` and `b` and if yes which one and why its is best one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1). Maybe, this would be referred to as "Boolean expression" in Mathematica speech.

2.) `SameQ` is problematic as it does not respect the logical content:

```
hamlet = Or[be, Not[be]];
a = SameQ[hamlet, True]
b= Equivalent[hamlet, True]
```

> False
>
> be || ! be

So using these in later computions may lead to wrong results:

```
Simplify[a]
Simplify[b]
```

> False
>
> True

The `TrueQ`/`Equal` combo is similarly dangerous as `TrueQ` will return `False` whenever it gets a symbolic expression as arguments that does not evaluate immediately to `True`. Better not use it here.

Moreover, `Equivalent` may be able to perform some simplifications that `Equal` cannot perform because using `Equivalent` implies that its arguments are Boolean expressions.

3.) Some more simplifications are performed by `TautologyQ`:

```
TautologyQ[Equivalent[hamlet, True]]
```

> True

4.) In life, there is usually never one best way to do anything. For example,`SameQ` is a very inexpensive test and if it evaluates to `True`, you are done. `Equivalent` and `TautologyQ` have to perform actual computations, taking a bit longer.

Comment: Here `TautologyQ[Equivalent[hamlet, True]]` as far as I understand first is evaluates `Equivalent[hamlet, True]` and only after `TautologyQ[]`. `TautologyQ[]` receives the only final result of `Equivalent[]` which can only be  `True` or`False`. In that case, how `TautologyQ[]` can perform more simplifications? What more simplifications can be done on `True` or`False`?

....

Comment: ....
Or maybe `TautologyQ[]` forces `Equivalent[]` to perform more simplifications before `Equivalent[]` evaluates and returns the result? In that case, `TautologyQ[]` is only here to force `Equivalent[]` to make additional simplifications and nothing more?

Comment: For example, `TautologicalQ` might search the subexpressions for short-circuits.  `Equivalent` alone probably does not do that for performance reasons.

Comment: So, `TautologyQ[]` is only here to force `Equivalent[]` to make additional simplifications before `Equivalent[]` actually evaluates and nothing more?

Comment: I am even not sure whether `Equivalent` performs any but the very simplest simplifications at all. Working seldomly with these things and not being a developer, I have few further knowledge about these things. All I can say: The general strategy about simplification in Mathematica is so that the user has  to actively ask for more expensive simplifications. (Compare, e.g. `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` and the fact that they have further options that can be tuned.)

Comment: What about `Equivalent[FullSimplify[hamlet], True]`? Is it the same or maybe better than `TautologyQ[Equivalent[hamlet, True]]` ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I have the feeling that the second one might make you happier on the long run.